Formatting complexity theory problems?
I am aware there are several excellent packages in CTAN for typesetting algorithms. However, I often need to first describe the problem the algorithm is solving, and I can't seem to find a package that lets me do this smoothly. For example, the following problem came up in one of my classes:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabular}

\begin{document}

\section{Algorithm Description}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.8\linewidth}}
\textit{Problem:} & \textsc{OrthogonalVectors} \\ 
\textit{Given:} & Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$\\ 
\textit{Output:} & Are there $a = (a_1,\cdots, a_d)\in A$ and $b= (b_1,\cdots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0$\\ 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10px}

\end{document}


I'd like help and advice defining a problem environment that I can stick into a .sty file that would streamline such definitions in my notes, taking care of the fonts and formatting. I'd like to be able to write a command like this and get the same output as above, with an optional framed argument:
  \begin{decproblem}{framed}
    Problem: & OrthogonalVectors\\
    Given: & Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$\\
    Output: & Are there $a = (a_1,\cdots, a_d)\in A$ and $b= (b_1,\cdots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0?$\\ 
  \end{decproblem}

Many CS books seem to have something like this defined; here is C. Moore's The Nature of Computation which does this:

I have seen this similar question but unfortunately don't know enough LaTeX to adapt the solution there.

Can you please somehow sketch and add how you want your result to appear? Makes solutions easier. Thank you

@MS-SPO  Thanks for engaging. I'd like the result to appear the same as the MWE (possibly framed), just without me having to specify all the formatting again each time. I've edited the post to reflect this.

Using tabularray I defined two environments: decproblem and its star variant decproblem* (the latter will produce a frame).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{decproblem}{+b}{
  \begin{tblr}{column{1}={font=\itshape,wd=0.15\linewidth},column{2}={wd=0.7\linewidth},cell{1}{2}={font=\scshape}}
    #1
  \end{tblr}
}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{decproblem*}{+b}{
  \begin{tblr}{column{1}={font=\itshape,wd=0.15\linewidth},column{2}={wd=0.7\linewidth},cell{1}{2}={font=\scshape},hline{1},hline{4}={1pt},vline{1},vline{3}={1pt}}
    #1
  \end{tblr}
}{}
\begin{document}

\section{Algorithm Description}

\begin{decproblem}
  Problem: & Orthogonal Vectors \\
  Given: & Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$ \\
  Output: & Are there $a = (a_1,\cdots, a_d)\in A$ and $b= (b_1,\cdots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0$? \\ 
\end{decproblem}

\noindent
\begin{decproblem*}
  Problem: & Orthogonal Vectors \\
  Given: & Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$ \\
  Output: & Are there $a = (a_1,\cdots, a_d)\in A$ and $b= (b_1,\cdots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0$? \\ 
\end{decproblem*}

\end{document}



This suits me perfectly, thank you!

I propose two tcolorbox based environments.
The contents is split at the \tag command and the tag is typeset in a box 15% of the current line width. The text is set with a left skip of the same width.
If the argument to \tag is “Problem”, the accompanying text is printed in small caps.
The *-variant makes a frame around the description.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{decproblem}{+b}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=white,
    frame empty,
  ]
  \makedecproblem{#1}
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{decproblem*}{+b}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    sharp corners,
  ]
  \makedecproblem{#1}
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makedecproblem}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \tag } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \__luke_decproblem_tag:n ##1 }
  \setlength{\leftskip}{0.15\linewidth}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {\par\smallskip\normalfont}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__luke_decproblem_tag:n
 {
  \par\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[0.15\linewidth][l]{\itshape #1:}}
  \str_if_eq:eeT { \str_foldcase:n {#1} } {problem} { \scshape }
  \ignorespaces
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Algorithm Description}

\lipsum[37][1-3]

\begin{decproblem}
  \tag{Problem} Orthogonal Vectors
  \tag{Given} Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length 
    $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$
  \tag{Output} Are there $a = (a_1,\dots, a_d)\in A$ and 
    $b=(b_1,\dots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0$?
\end{decproblem}

\lipsum[38][1-3]

\begin{decproblem*}
  \tag{Problem} Orthogonal Vectors
  \tag{Given} Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length 
    $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$
  \tag{Output} Are there $a = (a_1,\dots, a_d)\in A$ and 
    $b=(b_1,\dots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0$?
\end{decproblem*}

\lipsum[39][1-3]

\end{document}



Here is one way to do it: abstract your structure into a \newcommand, i.e. separate content (passed parameters) from presentation (done inside the \newcommand).
\theoprob could be the name of your theoretical problem:

you pass 3 parameters (accessed as #1, #2 and #3)
you copy your layout presentation inside the macro
you replace the content by #1, #2 and #3

To avoid insertion of unwanted blanks you better end each line sharp (i.e. without blanks) by %.
\newcommand\theoprob[3]{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.8\linewidth}}%
    \textit{Problem:} & \textsc{#1}\\ %
    \textit{Given:} & #2\\%
    \textit{Output:} & #3\\%
    \end{tabular}%
    %
    \vspace{10px}}

To put a frame around it you could either rewrite said macro to take options, or, what I prefer doing, have a new macro, which puts a \fbox around \theprob:
\ftheoprob:
\newcommand\ftheoprob[3]{\fbox{\theoprob{#1}{#2}{#3}}\vspace{10px}}

\fbox seems to absorb vertical spacings at the end, so I had to add it there. These kinds of problems you identify e.g. by putting some blindtext.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tabular}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\theoprob[3]{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.8\linewidth}}%
    \textit{Problem:} & \textsc{#1}\\ %
    \textit{Given:} & #2\\%
    \textit{Output:} & #3\\%
    \end{tabular}%
    %
    \vspace{10px}}

\newcommand\ftheoprob[3]{\fbox{\theoprob{#1}{#2}{#3}}\vspace{10px}}
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\section{Algorithm Description}
\lipsum[5]

\begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.8\linewidth}}
\textit{Problem:} & \textsc{OrthogonalVectors} \\ 
\textit{Given:} & Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$\\ 
\textit{Output:} & Are there $a = (a_1,\cdots, a_d)\in A$ and $b= (b_1,\cdots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0$\\ 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10px}


\theoprob{OrthogonalVectors}
         {Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$}
         {Are there $a = (a_1,\cdots, a_d)\in A$ and $b= (b_1,\cdots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0$}

\ftheoprob{OrthogonalVectors}
         {Two sets $A$ and $B$ each containing $n$ vectors of length $d$ with components from $\{0, 1\}$}
         {Are there $a = (a_1,\cdots, a_d)\in A$ and $b= (b_1,\cdots,b_d)\in B$ such that $\sum_i a_i \times b_i = 0$}
         
 \lipsum[5]

\end{document}


BTW, px may be a useful unit in website programming. In Latex you'd better use e.g. pt. Probably you meant \bigskip , which "insertes 1 blank line", anyway ;-)

I don't know if it helps at this point but I found that this university from New Zealand has a manual for creating databases of problems using LaTeX and the bibtex format.
https://www.math.canterbury.ac.nz/~m.hickman/LaTeX/ProblemsManual.pdf
in here they use the package problems
\usepackage{problems}

Yo can add the solution to the prblem with:
\usepackage[solution]{problems}

The problem must be saved to an ASCII file with Bibtex like syntax
@QUESTION{2-1,
    problem = {The one dimensional (linear) wave equation is given by
    $$ \pder[2]{u}{t^2} = c^2 \, \pder[2]{u}{x^2} \label{wave} $$
    where $c$ is the (constant) wave speed. Show that this equation
    may be rewritten as the coupled system of two first order 
    equations
    \begin{align*}
    u_t - c \, u_x &= w \\ w_t + c \, w_x &= 0.
    \end{align*}
    Hence show that the general solution of (\ref{wave}) is
    \[ u(x, \ t) = F(x-ct) + G(x+ct) \]
    for arbitrary functions $F$ and $G$.},
    solution = {Let $w=u_t-cu_x$. Then
    \[ w_t+cw_x = (u _t-cu_x)_t + c(u_t-cu_x)_x
    = u_{tt}-c^2\,u_{xx} = 0. \] Solving $w_t+cw_x=0 $ by the method
    of characteristics, gives $w(x, \ t) = P(x-ct)$ for some arbitrary
    function $P$. Thus \[ u_t - c \, u_x = P(x-ct). \] The 
    characteristic
    variables for this equation are $t=\tau$ and $x = \xi -c \tau$. In
    characteristic variables, the equation is
    \[ U_\tau = P(\xi-c\tau-c\tau) = P(\xi-2c\tau) \] and so
    \[ U = F(\xi) + G(\xi-2c\tau) \] where
    $G’=-\frac{P}{2c}$ (an arbitrary function!). Finally we obtain
    \[ u(x, \ t) = F(x+ct) +G(x+ct-2ct) = F(x+ct) + G(x-ct) \]
    as required.},
    keywords = {tutorial, characteristics},
    owner = {msh51},
    timestamp = {2009.03.02}
    }

By calling in the tag 2-1 in @QUESTION{2-1, with the command    \problems{2-1} you can produce the following output


Link only answer are viewed as bad answer. If the link is broken, the answer is lost.

Maybe better post this as a comment.

Just edited the answer. Thanks for the feedback as well.

@DavidBarcene It's better, thanks. Could you add a real minimal working example (MWE) that anyone can copy, paste and compile?
